# Magento - Adding text after price on specific product page

Tags: magento, custom-attributes, product

One of my products in Magento is sold only by the dozen. I need the price to reflect that visually for the customer. The way Magento handles that by default is simply "$xx.xx". I need it to read, and **only** for this one specific product, "$xx.xx Per Dozen". I know it's a matter of adding an attribute (maybe) and somehow calling it from somewhere given product ID, but I have no idea how to go about this. Currently I have an attribute called `perdozen` as a text area. That's about it. From here I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Tier prices might get you there with a minimum quantity of 12, sold in increments of 12. This you can setup on the product - an extra attribute might be overkill if one product.

Another avenue to explore is conditional CSS, 'PACK of 12' in the product title might make it clear too.

Comment: I've already set up tier pricing, however adding "per dozen" right next to the price is what I'd also like to do.

Comment: Copy app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml into your theme and edit it. `$_price['price_qty']==12` is the logic you need.